# Create an XML from a DataTable

Tags: c#, xml, linq, datatable, dataset

[image: DataTable In C# of following format]

Using C# : I want to convert this table into XML. **Please ignore the mistakes in row names**. This is test data. I have given sample of two columns converted to xml and the corresponding rows as attributes . But i actually want for all columns. This is a Datatable.

```
 <ListDataCollateralDials>
                                <DataCollateralDials Type="Conv">
                                    <Multiplier>1</Multiplier>
                                    <Seasoning>1</Seasoning>
                                    <Lockin>1</Lockin>
                                    <Multiplier>1</Multiplier>
                                    <ElbowShift>0</ElbowShift>
                                    <Steepness>1</Steepness>
                                    <Burnout>1</Burnout>
                                    <Adjustment >1</Adjustment>
                                    <Effect>1</Effect>
                                    <Decay>1</Decay>
                                    <Outs>1</Outs>
                                    <Base>700</Base>
                                    <Slope>1</Slope>
                                    <Base>80</Base>
                                    <Slope2>1</Slope2>
                                    <Base2>200</Base2>
                                    <Slope3>1</Slope3>
                                    <Height>0</Height>
                                    <Length>0</Length>
                                    <Height2>0</Height2>
                                    <Length2>0</Length2>
                                    <Elbow>0</Elbow>
                                                 <Multiplier2>1</Multiplier2>
                                    <Multiplier3>1</Multiplier3>

                                </DataCollateralDials>
<DataCollateralDials Type="Conv">
                                <Multiplier>1</Multiplier>
                                <Seasoning>1</Seasoning>
                                <Lockin>1</Lockin>
                                <Multiplier>1</Multiplier>
                                <ElbowShift>0</ElbowShift>
                                <Steepness>1</Steepness>
                                <Burnout>1</Burnout>
                                <Adjustment >1</Adjustment>
                                <Effect>1</Effect>
                                <Decay>1</Decay>
                                <Outs>1</Outs>
                                <Base>700</Base>
                                <Slope>1</Slope>
                                <Base>80</Base>
                                <Slope2>1</Slope2>
                                <Base2>200</Base2>
                                <Slope3>1</Slope3>
                                <Height>0</Height>
                                <Length>0</Length>
                                <Height2>0</Height2>
                                <Length2>0</Length2>
                                <Elbow>0</Elbow>
                                <Multiplier2>1</Multiplier2>
                                <Multiplier3>1</Multiplier3>

                            </DataCollateralDials>
</ListDataCollateralDials>
```

Comment: * <DataCollateralDials Type="glen"> in second xelement. This was typo error

Comment: use DataTable.WriteXml http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static string ToXml(this DataTable table, int metaIndex = 0)
{
    XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
        new XElement(table.TableName,
            from column in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
            where column != table.Columns[metaIndex]
            select new XElement(column.ColumnName,
                from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                select new XElement(row.Field<string>(metaIndex), row[column])
                )
            )
        );

    return xdoc.ToString();
}
```

This worked great for me. Thanks stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

`DataTable`s are designed to iterate over rows, not columns like you have.  There's nothing built-in to persist a `DataTable` in column-major order.  You're going to have use custom code.  Pseudo-code would be something like:

```
foeeach(DataColumn)
  if(name != "Name")
    output column header
    foreach(DataRow) 
      output row value
```

Comment: I have to skip the first column . If someone can provide me with the code it would be great

Comment: Well I added skipping the "Name" column but you're going to have to do some work on your own.  If you have specific questions you can post them as new questions here but I doubt you're going to get someone to write the whole thing for you.

Answer (score 2):

you can try using this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml.aspx

```
DataTable youdatatable = GetData();
System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
 youdatatable.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema, true);
 PrintOutput(writer);
```