# Linq to Datatable and Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, c#-4.0, datatable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create an XML from a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072927/create-an-xml-from-a-datatable)

How to create an XML from DataTable using LINQ . I don't have enough experience with LINQ .

Any good tutorials that i can follow.

Convert the below datatable to xml using LINQ. Ignore errors in rows as its test data. I have previously asked this question on stackoverflow. Got one good solution of iterating over datarows and columns. But it would be better if i do it using LINQ.

[image: DataTable]

[image: XML]

Comment: Here's the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072927/create-an-xml-from-a-datatable).

Comment: Please clarify, the answer in your original question works and seems quite good. Why would using linq be better?

Comment: I would require very messy coding. It wouldn't be dynamic.

Comment: public static string ToXml(this DataTable table, int metaIndex = 0)
{
    XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
        new XElement(table.TableName,
            from column in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
            where column != table.Columns[metaIndex]
            select new XElement(column.ColumnName,
                from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                select new XElement(row.Field<string>(metaIndex), row[column])
                )
            )
        );

    return xdoc.ToString();
}

Comment: This approach worked best for me. It served well. And much cleaner code. Thanks Stackoverflow for this approach