# Elements in xml file breaks while writing to xml file from datatable

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, streamreader

1. Hi folks! I saving creating an xml file by using below code.
2. The problem is that the element gets break.
3. How or what should i do to make sure that elements do not break :(

```
//the below method creates an xml file from datatable
private void Write_To_XML_File(String xml_file, DataTable dt)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(log_folder))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(log_folder);
    }

    xml_file = Path.Combine(log_folder, xml_file);
    FileStream File_Stream; XmlTextWriter xml_writer; UTF8Encoding UTF8_Encoding;
    File_Stream = new FileStream(xml_file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
    UTF8_Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
    using (xml_writer = new XmlTextWriter(File_Stream, UTF8_Encoding))
    {
        dt.WriteXml(xml_writer, XmlWriteMode.DiffGram);
    }

}//Write_To_XML_File

//Here how it breaks the element:

<DocumentElement>
    <person_info>
        <person>"ABC"</person>
        <city>"London"</city>
    </person_info>
    don"</city></person_info>
</DocumentElement>
```

Comment: check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13073226/1745795

Comment: The xml is not valid .  You have one opening tab <city> and then two closing tags </city> without another opening tag.  The input string to the method xml_file is probably corrupted.

Comment: @jdweng well basically that is the main concern here. Why datatable outputs broken element though it appears well in datatable :(

Comment: Why aren't you use the dt.WriteXml(filename)?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by just change below

```
File_Stream = new FileStream(xml_file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);

===to

File_Stream = new FileStream(xml_file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
```